# QT Maximizing QGraphicsWebView in QMainWindow

Tags: fill, qtwebkit, maximize

I need to use QtWebKit with CSS 3D support, that's why i used QGraphicsWebView and QGLWidget, the code looks like this:

*MainWindow.hpp:*

```c++
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsWebView>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT;
    public:
        MainWindow(const char *url);
        void init();
    private:
        QGraphicsView *gview;
        QGraphicsScene *scene;
        QGraphicsWebView *web_view;
};
```

*MainWindow.cpp:*

```c++
#include "MainWindow.hpp"
#include <QWebSettings>
#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QStatusBar>

MainWindow::MainWindow(const char *url) {
    setWindowTitle("QTWebKit Experiment");

    QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::AcceleratedCompositingEnabled, true);
    gview = new QGraphicsView(this);
    gview->setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
    gview->setViewport(new QGLWidget(this));

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(gview);
    web_view = new QGraphicsWebView();

    scene->addItem(web_view);
    gview->setScene(scene);
    web_view->load(QString(url));
    web_view->setResizesToContents(true);

    setCentralWidget(gview);
}

void MainWindow::init() {
    show();
}
```

The problem is that **web_view** doesn't fill the QMainWindow widget. What should I do to make website fill the window?

-> [Screenshot - google in resized QMainWindow](http://regalis.com.pl/images/web_view.png)

Comment: Did you solve it somehow? If yes, did you get scrollbars when making the window larger and then again smaller, i.e. the content size doesn't change for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set size policy before adding QGraphicsWebView to QGraphicsScene?

```
web_view->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding);
```

You should also add your widgets into a layout (The property sizePolicy is a layout behavior, so you need to put your widgets into a layout) QVboxLayout is a good one for your needs.